# Code that is working in production no longer works in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have code that is working fine in production.  I screwed up a few line on the master branch, deleted my local repo, recloned it and now the app is throwing this error:

```
undefined method `user_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Now this is silly because my code looks 100% to me.. the view:

```
<div id="comment-container">
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>


  <div class="well well-sm comment-well">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="comment-name"><%= comment.user.user_name %></button>

  <div id="com-text">
    <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  </div>
  </div>


 <% end %>
</div>
```

and here is my controller action for show:

```
def show
@post = Post.includes(:user).find(params[:id])
@comments = @post.comments.order('created_at desc')
end
```

my association are correct and my user has a user_name!

This code is working in production!  This is driving me crazy I went backwards tonight!

Comment: so every comment now has a user_id of nil? how did that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the particular ***post*** doesn't have a ***user*** associated with it. To resolve the error, use [**try**](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try).

```
<%= comment.user.try(:user_name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `user` is `nil`. Maybe you removed the user from the database and did not have `dependent: :destroy` in your relation.

If a comment can exist without having a user, your best bet would be to use delegation to avoid this kind of issue.

In your comment model, you could add

`delegate :user_name, to: :user, allow_nil: true`

and after, you can write `comment.user_name`, which will return the correct result when present, and `nil` otherwise.
Note that it still needs to query the `users` table, so you still need the `includes(:user)` to avoid the `N+1` queries issue.

Comment: all my comments user_id's we're set to nil, how did that happen..has to be in my comments controller doesn't it?